# How to add links to sidebar without using a block?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

does anyone know how to add links or HTML onto the left sidebar of a drupal theme without using a block? I am using drupal 7.14. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you not want to use a block? Knowing your reasoning/problem may help someone answer your question more appropriately?  Also, are these links something you are trying to do on a single page or is this something you may want to re-use?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using the  [_phptemplate_variables](http://api.drupal.org/api/5/function/_phptemplate_variables) function in template.php in your theme directory.

```
function _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars) {
  if ($hook == 'page') {
    foreach (array('left','right') as $region) {
      $vars[$region] = drupal_get_content($region);
      return $vars; 
    }
  }
}
```

And just call this function below where you want to display the link.

```
$output = l('some link text','node/1234');
drupal_set_content('left', $output);
```

Comment: Note that `_phptemplate_variables` is deprecated. Alternate for D6 and above is [`template_preprocess`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7)